# How to reload (refresh) data on grid in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have on click image and in that method i have this two pictures to set source for them:

```
image4.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("Cards/" + player12.First() + ".png");
```

and

```
image5.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("Cards/" + comp1.First() + ".png");
```

i have timer to wait but they show at the same time when execution of the method will be done. I want to reload grid after first image4.Source and then stop for two secounds with timer and then show image5.source.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class for delayed execution:

```
public class OneShowDispatcherTimer
{
    public static void FireAfter(TimeSpan inverval, Action callback)
    {
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer()
            {
                Interval = interval
            };
            Timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
            {
                Timer.Stop();
                callback();
            };
            Timer.Start();
        });
    }
}
```

And use in that manner:

```
OneShowDispatcherTimer.FireAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), () =>
{
    image4.Source = ...

    OneShowDispatcherTimer.FireAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), () =>
    {
        image5.Source = ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Dude thanks a lot. Did you know how to make break (pause) in execution but everthyng in the past code to be display on UI in my case i want to see all cards (images) how computer flipping over. I want to see every single not just the last one.

Comment: Create `Animations` and subscribe to `Completed` event to execute code after it completes

Comment: Hey dude thanks a lot and sory but can you give me some litle example how to do that. Thanks again

Comment: `animation.Completed += (s, e) => { //do something }; animation.Begin();`